# Wireshark Troubles

Tags: 13.04, vmware, wireshark

I'm only able to watch my own data through a network and nothing else. I have no clue what to do anymore after trying a lot of different things. Im running Ubuntu 13.04 on VMWare.

Comment: In a VM you cannot access all settings of your real computer's hardware. So you cannot put your network card into monitoring mode. If you want to capture all the data flowing through the network I suggest you use a tool like ettercap for a man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, allowing promiscuous mode of the virtual LAN adapater and not using NAT (also in the VM settings) could help.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/247686620c6bc213a7c3c2bd916c4704 Could this be affecting it? I am kind of confused about the promiscuous mode thing. On wireshark in the interface options, I do have Capture all in promiscuous mode checked in the box. When I try to run things on Ubuntu, it usually tells me I don't have permission and giving myself permissions usually doesn't work.